# How to return specific values from a rest api

Tags: rest, api, soapui, postman

I am working with a Rest API. When I use GET, it returns the below values.

```
firstName
lastName
email
phone
id
```

In one of my tests I need to only return 2-3 values e.g `firstName, lastName and email`. I'm unable to understand how I can achieve that.

I'm using both SoapUI and Postman. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with just ignoring the phone and id if you're not gonna use them?

Comment: That's what I am not able to accomplish. When I use get on https://api.qa.sample.ninja/users?limit=5 

I'm getting all the above values. I need to test in a way that it returns only 2-3 values.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it wrong. You're not consuming the API, you're building it. Removing fields should be a pretty simple task when you have access to the API's source. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to return specific fields when I use the Get method. Instead of all 5 fields, I only need 3 fields.

Comment: Why do you care? The fields are small, you can just ignore them

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the Rest API. You can use GrapQL to achieve that.